# to save every input is entered in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Everytime I typed in an input the Localstorage gets the latest input and removes the earlier input basically it stores only one item. how can I store whatever I type in. I don't know how would I fix the problem tried a few things but still no use. Also when I refresh the page I want the localstorage details still be appeared on the list. Obviously the purpose of localstorage.

```js
var enterButton = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var item = document.getElementsByTagName("li");


function inputLength(){
    return input.value.length;
}

function listLength(){
    return item.length;
}

function load(){

}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li"); // creates an element "li"
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //makes text from input field the li text
    ul.appendChild(li); //adds li to ul
    input.value = ""; //Reset text input field


    //START STRIKETHROUGH
    // because it's in the function, it only adds it for new items
    function crossOut() {
        li.classList.toggle("done");
    }

    li.addEventListener("click",crossOut);
    //END STRIKETHROUGH


    // START ADD DELETE BUTTON
    var dBtn = document.createElement("button");
    dBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    li.appendChild(dBtn);
    dBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteListItem);
    // END ADD DELETE BUTTON


    //ADD CLASS DELETE (DISPLAY: NONE)
    function deleteListItem(){
        li.classList.add("delete")
    }
    //END ADD CLASS DELETE
}


function addListAfterClick(){
    var text = input.value;
    var object = [ ];

    object.push({value: text})
    localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(object));


    if (inputLength() == 0) { //makes sure that an empty input field doesn't create a li
        alert("Please insert a word");
    }else {
        createListElement();
    }

}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.which ===13) { //this now looks to see if you hit "enter"/"return"
        //the 13 is the enter key's keycode, this could also be display by event.keyCode === 13
        createListElement();
    }
}


enterButton.addEventListener("click",addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list-item").sortable();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>todo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Work To-Dos</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="helpText">
            <p id="first">Enter text into the input field to add items to your list.</p>
            <p id="second">Click the item to mark it as complete.</p>
            <p id="third">Click the "X" to remove the item from your list.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="New item...">
            <button id="enter"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Empty List -->
    <div>
        <div class="listItems">
            <ul id="list-item">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of this line

```
localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(object))
```

What this means is that you overwrite the 'todo' key every time you save a new todo. I think a more proper approach will be retrieving what ever the value is in the todo before adding new one. Something like creating a copy of the todo object then inserting new one and saving back. Take a look at the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)